# In Microsoft Outlook 2010, how do I sort Tasks by Due Date so they are ascending, but things without a Due Date are at the bottom?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, tasks, to-do

I'm not sure if this is possible, but what I would like to have is a list of tasks such that the first thing in the list is the thing that is due first. Things that do you have an explicit due date should be listed at the bottom of the list, below the thing with the most distant due date. In the normal ascending order, things without a due date are displayed first, followed by the thing with the closest due date.

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on "Arrange by:"
- Click "View Settings"
- Click "Filter"
- In tab "Tasks" set "Time" to "due" + "Anytime"

Now tasks without a due date are hidden from view. Deactive this filter to see them again.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is select the records with no due date and drag them to the bottom. They will stay at the bottom, but they will get "today's" date. Hence they will appear last.

Comment: So what happens tomorrow? Will they all be overdue? Because that's really not a good alternative.

Comment: Yes the will be overdue.
In this case just pick a date in the future and you are good to go.

Comment: That's really not what I'm looking for. That means every day I need to sort, select tasks (ignoring any that may actually be overdue) and change their date. It also doesn't accurately reflect that they don't have a due date. The fact that a task doesn't have a due date is important to me and shouldn't be lost. Is what I want not possible with Outlook?

Comment: I don't think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this in my opinion is to highlight all the "no date" entries and set them to "next week". This way "due today" items will appear first. You may then want to be more specific with entries you genuinely want to be next week to differentiate them.

Works for me! Hope this helps anyone still interested!

Answer (score 0):

You could do is to set the tasks with due dates as "high priority" and then order by priority and then by due date so that the "high priority" tasks area always displayed on the top regardless of their due dates.